# Java: DefaultListModel and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlist

Is there a way to add all the Strings in an array to a JList? I am using the DefaultListModel and I have no idea how to use it. Isn't there a way to just use addElement then add the array? I tried but it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
package program;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    JList list = new JList(model);

    //JFrame, frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //JPanel, panel
    pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(pane);

    //JList, list

    String[] lists = {"asjd.txt", "okay.ss", "jsjs.okay.txt"};

    model.addElement(lists);

    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(3);

    listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));

    listScroller.setBounds(5, 5, 200, 300);
    pane.add(listScroller);




}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own loop:

```
for (String item: lists)
    model.addElement( item );
```

Also, the frame should be made visible AFTER all the components have been added to the frame.

```
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));
listScroller.setBounds(5, 5, 200, 300);
```

Don't use setPreferredSize(). You already used setVisibleRowCount() to control the size of the JList.

Don't use setBounds(). That is the job of the layout manager.

Answer (score 1):

JList contains a constructor

```
JList(ListModel <E> dataModel)
```

which means you could create your own ListModel object which accepts your array.